# find the position of elements in series 2 in series 1..series 1: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] series 2[1,3,7] Sample Output: [0,2,6]

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, range, runtime-error

> series 1: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
> series 2[1,3,7]
>
> Sample Output: [0,2,6]

```
import ast,sys
    import pandas as pd
    input_str = sys.stdin.read()
    input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
    series1=pd.Series(input_list[0])
    series2=pd.Series(input_list[1])
    z =series2.size
    c=[]
    for i in range (0,z):
        if series2[i] in series1:
            c.append(series1.index(series2[i]))
    
out_list=c
print(list(map(int,out_list)))
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Does this code not work?

Comment: since both your series are arranged in ascending order, you could do `pd.np.where(pd.np.in1d(series1,series2))` or even `series1[series1.isin(series2)].index`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use pandas Series, or will something like this work?

```
in1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
in2 = [1,3,7]

output = [in1.index(x) for x in in2]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 6]
```